# Blackberry : How to change image periodically in my screen?

Tags: blackberry

I want to change the image in my application screen periodically.

how can i implement it ?

is there any timer control(like in iPhone) for BlackBerry ?

waiting for your suggessions...

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
   try {
                    timer = new Timer();
                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ImageTask(), 0, 5000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // do nothing
                }

                private class ImageTask extends TimerTask {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Test Printing..");

                    }
                }
```